# Using BatchCollisions on Form's recordset?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Hoping to get more information on what column, table or row is causing a write conflict in a MS Access 2010 project, I wrote the following code:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Call printCollisionInfo(Me.Recordset, Me.name)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Call printCollisionInfo(Me.Recordset, Me.name)
End Sub
```

Method `printCollisionInfo` is:

```
Public Sub printCollisionInfo(rst As Recordset, formName As String)
    Dim msg As String
    msg = Now & " From " & formName & ": " & rst.BatchCollisionCount & " collisions"

    Debug.Print msg
End Sub
```

But when calling `rst.BatchCollisionCount`, I get

```
"Operation is not supported for this type of object"
```

Is it because a form does not perform a dbUpdateBatch but some other type of update?  Can I set the form's update type?  Is there another way to see the SQL (with data values) or data that triggered the conflict?

Comment: Try using the explicit property `rst.BatchCollisionCount.Value`

Answer (score 1):

The `Recordset.BatchCollisionCount` property is only valid for **ODBCDirect** workspaces.

This is stated in the Access 2010 online help, but unfortunately not on the MSDN page:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198240(v=office.14).aspx

Look at how the recordset is set up in the example on that page. This is about as far from a bound form's recordset as it can be.

Here is an intro about ODBCDirect: http://www.avdf.com/may97/art_optimist.html

This technique is old, but the fact, that your question is #11 on my google search, gives you a hint about how many people use it...

I suggest a new question where you describe your setup and the error(s) you get.